# SELinux problem during RPMS repository configuration with Ansible

Tags: ansible, rpm, selinux, rhel8, shibboleth-sp

I am using this Ansible task to deploy an rpm package to an RHEL8 server:

```
- name: Add the shibboleth Repository configuration
  yum_repository:
    name: security_shibboleth
    description: Shibboleth (CentOS_7)
    setype: rpm-md
    mirrorlist: https://shibboleth.net/cgi-bin/mirrorlist.cgi/CentOS_7
    gpgkey:
      - https://shibboleth.net/downloads/service-provider/RPMS/repomd.xml.key
      - https://shibboleth.net/downloads/service-provider/RPMS/cantor.repomd.xml.key
    gpgcheck: true
    enabled: true
  tags:
    - shibboleth
```

However, the task fails with this SELinux error:

```
fatal: [proxy_server_46]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cur_context": ["unconfined_u", "object_r", "system_conf_t", "s0"], "gid": 0, "group": "root", "input_was": [null, null, "rpm-md", null], "mode": "0644", "msg": "invalid selinux context: [Errno 22] Invalid argument", "new_context": ["unconfined_u", "object_r", "rpm-md", "s0"], "owner": "root", "path": "/etc/yum.repos.d/security_shibboleth.repo", "secontext": "unconfined_u:object_r:system_conf_t:s0", "size": 312, "state": "file", "uid": 0}
```

Any ideas what's going wrong here? Googling for this error type unfortunately did not deliver any helpful results.

Comment: You need only to remove the line with `setype: rpm-md`...

Comment: @U880D is correct. If you look at the error message, `invalid selinux context` suggests that `rpm-md` is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`yum_repository` module (to) Add or remove YUM repositories](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_repository_module.html) is more or less to create a YUM repository file (`.repo`) under location `/etc/yum.repos.d/` only. This in mind, a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Create and add .repo file
    yum_repository:
      name: security_shibboleth
      description: Shibboleth (CentOS_7)
      mirrorlist: https://shibboleth.net/cgi-bin/mirrorlist.cgi/CentOS_7
      gpgkey:
        - https://shibboleth.net/downloads/service-provider/RPMS/repomd.xml.key
        - https://shibboleth.net/downloads/service-provider/RPMS/cantor.repomd.xml.key
      gpgcheck: true
      enabled: true
```

will generate the "text" file in INI style.

```ini
~/test$ cat /etc/yum.repos.d/security_shibboleth.repo
[security_shibboleth]
async = 1
enabled = 1
gpgcheck = 1
gpgkey = https://shibboleth.net/downloads/service-provider/RPMS/repomd.xml.key
        https://shibboleth.net/downloads/service-provider/RPMS/cantor.repomd.xml.key
mirrorlist = https://shibboleth.net/cgi-bin/mirrorlist.cgi/CentOS_7
name = Shibboleth (CentOS_7)
```

Looking at the module [Parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_repository_module.html#parameters) documentation one may notice that **there is no parameter for `type`**.

```yaml
TASK [Create and add .repo file] *******************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false
  msg: 'Unsupported parameters for (yum_repository) module: type. Supported parameters include: seuser, ip_resolve, proxy_password, reposdir, includepkgs, owner, bandwidth, cost, file, mirrorlist_expire, exclude, sslclientkey (client_key), keepalive, module_hotfixes, group, failovermethod, unsafe_writes, deltarpm_metadata_percentage, gpgkey, setype, http_caching, priority, serole, mirrorlist, params, gpgcheck, include, sslclientcert (client_cert), proxy_username, username, ui_repoid_vars, metadata_expire, description, repo_gpgcheck, selevel, sslcacert (ca_cert), baseurl, sslverify (validate_certs), gpgcakey, s3_enabled, state, proxy, async, password, retries, protect, ssl_check_cert_permissions, throttle, name, deltarpm_percentage, metalink, enabled, skip_if_unavailable, keepcache, mode, timeout, enablegroups, metadata_expire_filter, attributes (attr).'
```

It is also not necessary to set such on plain Red Hat / Fedora / Cent OS distributions. For some background information see [Red Hat Bugzilla - Bug 1373317 - RFE: Add "type=rpm-md" and "repo_gpgcheck=0" to Fedora repo files](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1373317).

Whereby a `type` would be necessary to describe the repository for the underlaying package manager in more detail and which is not necessary in the given case, the parameter `setype` for setting

> *The type part of the SELinux filesystem object context.*

to `rpm-md` of course and obviously will not exist. Therefore the error message

```yaml
invalid selinux context: [Errno 22] Invalid argument", "new_context": ["unconfined_u", "object_r", "rpm-md", "s0"]
```

**To Summarize**

repo.`type != setype`.

**How to resolve?**

from most to less recommended ...

- Just remove the line `setype: rpm-md`
- Use the [`template` module (to) Template a file out to a target host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html) with `dest: /etc/yum.repos.d/security_shibboleth.repo` from a respecting Jinj2 Template
- Citation for module documentation: "*If you wish to update an existing repository definition use [`community.general.ini_file`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ini_file_module.html) instead.*"
- Use [`ini_file` module (to create) settings in INI files](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ini_file_module.html) from the beginnig
- Use [`lineinfile` module (to) Manage lines in text files](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html) to add the line `type: rpm-md` afterwards
- Change or enhance the code of [`ansible/modules/yum_repository.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/yum_repository.py)

---

*... interesting is that according the actual module source code [`yum_repository.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/yum_repository.py#L451) there seems to be no parameters `selevel`, `serole`, `setype` and `seuser` (anymore). It wasn't possible to find when and where they were introduced or removed. They were there at least at [Ansible Issue #23913](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/23913) and in Ansible version 2.2, but not anymore in Ansible version 2.8. The parameters are also reported in my `ansible [core 2.11.12]` via `ansible-doc yum_repository` even if the source code says they are not there ...* :-/

Comment: Thx for the comprehensive explanation!!